Expose Argo CD UI from Ingress Controller Kubernetes
I have this situation where I have a self managed kubernetes cluster using droplets in digital ocean. What's happening is that I have already one ingress controller under ingress-nginx namespace. It is working in terms of deploying services.
Now I have added argo cd in my cluster under the argocd namespace. What I want to do is to expose argocd-server using my existing Ingress Controller (or if there is other ways of using Ingress Controllers except nodeport because I can only use one public ip in my droplet). I tried to add the argocd-server service in my Ingress Controller rules but seems like it cannot access services outside its namespace directly.

Yes, ingresses are designed to be namespace specific so it's not an option. Also, if you wanted to use path based routing or something to that effect that would not work either since ArgoCD expects to be running in the root path and you will get 404 errors.

@MB ohh so if I want to expose it I should really directly use NodePort or a seperate Controller for it?

Yes I tried something like what you are trying but eventually had to get a separate LB pointing to the service.

Ohh I see. I will try this way. Thanks a lot!

Ingress objects are namespaced, meaning they must point to a Service object in the same namespace. Ingress controllers are cluster-scoped operators. You do not need to deploy a separate ingress controller per namespace.
I have worked with multiple ingress controllers over the years (Istio, Traefik, Contour, Nginx, ALB) and have never encountered a controller that only operated within a single namespace. There must be something else causing this issue.

I also want to add that ArgoCD not being able to work with a URL prefix is also not correct. Yes, by default ArgoCD configuration expects to be served at the root path, but this is a simple configuration override in the ArgoCD ConfigMap, configure server.basehref and/or server.rootpath, as documented here.
